# Opposite react component state changing

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, dom

I have a simple login form component that when I click, would like for the form to disappear and only display my json. I am a little rusty with working with react state, and appear to have the opposite effect of what I am trying. When I click on my button event, the json I am displaying will toggle appearing and disappearing, but the form stays static. I need the form to disappear and the page to populate with my grid.

Here is my components
**index.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import SignUp from '../SignUp';
import Cards from '../Articles/Cards';

export default class Gecko extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { requestedPostsThatWeGotFromGecko: null,  }
        this.clickMe = this.clickMe.bind(this)
  }

    
    clickMe = () => {
        const {requestedPostsThatWeGotFromGecko} = this.state;
        this.setState({ requestedPostsThatWeGotFromGecko: !requestedPostsThatWeGotFromGecko })
    }
    render() {
        console.log(this.state);
        return (
            <div className='gecko'>
                <SignUp login={() => this.clickMe()}/>
                {this.state.requestedPostsThatWeGotFromGecko &&
                    <Cards />
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**Sign up component**

```
import React from 'react';

export default class SignUp extends React.Component {

    render() {
        const onClick = () => {
            this.props.login();
            console.log('rich');
        }
        return (
            <div className='sign-up'>
                <table className='sign-up-form'>
                    <tbody>
                    <div class="gecko-signup__tabs"><button id="gecko-signup" data-selected="yes">Sign Up</button><button id="gecko-login" data-selected="">Log In</button></div>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <p id="signUpFree">Sign Up for Free</p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <div id="inputs-section">
                            <tr>
                                <td><input id="first" placeholder="First Name*" /></td>
                                <td><input id="last" placeholder="Last Name*" /></td>
                            </tr>
                        </div>
                        <tr>
                            <td colSpan="2"><input placeholder="Email Address*" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colSpan="2"><input placeholder="Set A Password*" /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colSpan="2"><input id="getStarted" type="submit" value="Get Started" onClick={onClick}/></td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**CardSetup component**

```
import React from 'react';
import SignUp from '../SignUp';


export default class Articles extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            requestedPostsThatWeGotFromGecko: [],
        }
    }
    
    componentDidMount(){
        const api = 'https://5d445466d823c30014771642.mockapi.io/api/v1/products';
        const request = new Request(api);
        // Fetch isn't browser compatible...Might should fix.
        fetch(request)
            .then(response => {
                if (response.status === 200) {
                    return response.json();
                } else {
                    throw new Error('Something went wrong on api server!');
                };
            }).then(response => {
                 
                this.setState({
                    requestedPostsThatWeGotFromGecko: response
                });
                
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error(error);
            });
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div className='articles'>
                
                {this.state.requestedPostsThatWeGotFromGecko.map(product => {
                    return (
                        <div className='flex-grid'>
                            <div className="card">
                                    <div className="overflow">
                                        <img className='productImage' src={product.image}></img>
                                    </div>
                                    <div className='card-body'>
                                        <p id='name'>{product.name}</p>
                                        <p id='description'>{product.description}</p>
                                        <p id='price'>{product.price} </p>
                                    </div>
                            
                            </div>
                        </div>
    );
    })
}
</div>
        )}}
```

**Final Cards component**

```
import React from 'react';
import Articles from './CardSetup';

export default class Cards extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return(
            
            <div className="cards">
                <h2>Products</h2>
                    <div className="column">
                        <Articles />
                    </div>
                    <div className="column">
                        <Articles />
                    </div>
                    <div className="column">
                        <Articles />
                    </div>
                    <div className="column">
                        <Articles />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I am pretty sure that I am setting the state incorrectly somewhere along the line after I press the button. I am thinking about jquery and wanting to "hide" the element but I know that is incorrect with react. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conditionally render `Cards` or `Signup` based on truthy/falsey value of `requestedPostsThatWeGotFromGecko`.

```
render() {
  const { requestedPostsThatWeGotFromGecko } = this.state;
  return (
    <div className="gecko">
      {requestedPostsThatWeGotFromGecko ? (
        <Cards />
      ) : (
        <SignUp login={() => this.clickMe()} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks Drew this worked perfectly. Just to clarify what is going on here... are we changing the state of requestedPostsThatWeGotFromGecko each time I click the button, which is in turn either displaying or not displaying the SignUp component?

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is what you want:

```
    render() {
        return (
            <div className='gecko'>
                {!this.state.requestedPostsThatWeGotFromGecko &&
                    <SignUp login={() => this.clickMe()}/>
                }
                {this.state.requestedPostsThatWeGotFromGecko &&
                    <Cards />
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to toggle between the Signup form and Cards based on `requestedPostsThatWeGotFromGecko` state variable.

So you can do something like this in your `index.jsx`:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className='gecko'>
      {this.state.requestedPostsThatWeGotFromGecko ?
        <Cards /> :
        <SignUp login={() => this.clickMe()} />
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is conditionally render the `SignUp` page on the basis of flag `requestedPostsThatWeGotFromGecko`.

**Note:** Important thing is you have to initialize it with false and make it true on the click from the `SignUp` page.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { requestedPostsThatWeGotFromGecko: false };
    this.clickMe = this.clickMe.bind(this)
}
   
render() {
const { requestedPostsThatWeGotFromGecko } = this.state;

return (
<div className="gecko">
  {requestedPostsThatWeGotFromGecko ? (
    <Cards />
  ) : (
    <SignUp login={() => this.setState({ requestedPostsThatWeGotFromGecko: true  })} />
  )}
</div>
  );
}
```